# Retrieve Azure Vault Secrets by Tag

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm using the following command to try to query Azure Key Vault secrets by Tag to see if they line up with the values I'm searching for.

This is the command I'm using

Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "CCID-VAULT" | select VaultName, Tags | where {$_.Tags["ENV"] -eq "test"}

However, when I run this I get the error - **Cannot index into a null array.**

I've tried suppressing the errors.  Some secrets will not have this tag applied to it?  Is there a way to just test for the existence of a tag?

Thank you - Greg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `Tags` is either null or omitted entirely if there are no tags, rather than be an empty hash table. Otherwise, I don't think it would throw this error. In which case, you could add another Where statement to first check that like this:

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "CCID-VAULT" | select VaultName, Tags | where {$_.Tags} | Where {$_.Tags["ENV"] -eq "test"}
```

Or add an `-and` in your first Where and have it check first:

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "CCID-VAULT" | select VaultName, Tags | where {$_.Tags -and $_.Tags["ENV"] -eq "test"}
```